# Specifying src of jQuery and Bootstrap files in html file

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I Capture Network in IE Developer Tools of a page created in Visual Studio 2012 the Result of .js and .css files loaded show as GET and the script files are loaded.

But when I run a page test.html in a browser (outside) of Visual Studio 2012, the Developer Tools columns show the following:
Method: Empty Column
Result: (File)
Type:   Empty Column
Received: 0 B
Taken: < 1 ms
Times:  Empty

The src for the .js and .css are defined in the test.html in absolute values as:

```
<script src="e:/test1/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="e:/test1/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Using file:// protocols in websites is generally not a good idea, get a wamp server or similar.

Comment: Please don't use abbreviated product names. What is "VS 2012"? Edit your question rather than responding in a comment.